# How to modify HTML content using javascript without ID?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is a website with a textarea in which I want to populate some default text as soon as the website loads but the problem is the textarea tag doesn't have an ID.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value="default text" ;
```

```html
<textarea name="details"  rows="5" cols="25" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;"></textarea>
```

I've tried the below code but it isn't working . Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value="default text" ;
```

[jsfiddle](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/dr51g8ez/1/)

TA.

Comment: `var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea[name="details"]');`

Comment: I do not think the answers linked to are the best BTW

Comment: Solved. I've used below code instead.

var menuItems = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for (var menuItemIndex = 0 ; menuItems.length ; menuItemIndex ++) {
   var currentMenuItem = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
   currentMenuItem.value = "default value";
}

thanks.